# Error while overloading operator + in myVector class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I know this question has appeared lots of times here and on the internet, but even by searching on this site I can't overload the `+` operator in `myvec` class. The strange thing is that I can overload the `=` operator, but as I write the declaration and definition of the operator `+`, I get an error.

More specifically, I declare the operator as

`myvec& myvec::operator+(const myvec& v, const myvec& w)`

and the definition is

```cpp
myvec& myvec::operator +(const myvec& v, const myvec& w)
{
    int d = v.size();
    myvec x(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        x(i) = v(i)+w(i);
    }
    return x;
}
```

In the following my little class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class myvec {
private:
    int dimension;
    double* data;

public:
    myvec(int dim);
    myvec(const myvec& v);
    ~myvec();

    int size() const;
    void Print();
    double& operator ()(int i);
    myvec& operator =(const myvec& v);
    myvec& operator +(const myvec& v, const myvec& w);
};


myvec::myvec(int dim)
{
    dimension = dim;
    data = new double[dim];

    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        data[i] = 0.0;
    }
}

myvec::myvec(const myvec& v)
{
    int dimensione = v.size();
    data = new double[dimensione];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensione; i++) {
        data[i] = v.data[i];
    }
}

myvec::~myvec()
{
    dimension = 0;
    delete[] data;
    data = NULL;
}

int myvec::size() const
{
    return dimension;
}

double& myvec::operator ()(int i)
{
    return data[i];
}

myvec& myvec::operator =(const myvec& v)
{

    int dim  = v.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
        data[i] = v.data[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

myvec& myvec::operator +(const myvec& v, const myvec& w)
{
    int d = v.size();
    myvec x(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        x(i) = v(i)+w(i);
    }
    return x;
}

void myvec::Print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        cout << data[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me the error:

```
testmyvec.cpp.cc:77:59: error: ‘myvec& myvec::operator+(const myvec&, const myvec&)’ must take either zero or one argument
```

It's clearly referring to the definition of the `+` operator. How can I fix it in order to overload the operator?

Comment: Is there a special reason you chose to overload `()` instead of the more common `[]`?

Comment: no, just because my book uses `()`. But that's working fine in my code. The problem is with `+` @Waqar

Comment: Remove the `&` from the return type, or there will be undfined behaviour.

Comment: Change the book. It must be really terrible if it is teaching you such things

Comment: @molbdnilo This was the declaration given in my book. It should be fine I guess

Comment: @Waqar Thanks for the advice :) Btw, could you tell me  how to fix this in order to let the compiler compile? 

Even if I remove `&`, it's still not working

Comment: @VoB `myvec& myvec::operator=(const myvec& v)` -- Your assignment operator leaks memory.  Your `vec` class has incorrect copy semantics because of this.  Thus any talk of `operator +` is a moot point until you fix the copying issues.  The second thing is that `operator +` should be returning a brand new `vec`, not a reference to the original vector.  Returning a reference to the original vector should be the job of `operator +=`, not `operator +`.

Comment: @VoB Then your book is wrong.

Comment: @VoB Just for the record, what book are you learning this from?  There are multiple things wrong with what you've posted, both in design and bugs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Thanks for all the multiple corrections. The book is "Parallel Scientific Computing in C++ and MPI
A Seamless Approach to Parallel Algorithms and their Implementation"

Comment: I think it's a case of the author knowing their discipline, but when applying C++ to implement it, well, that's another story.

Comment: @VoB -- [See this to fix your assignment operator](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61a2f46730148742)

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie for this last corrections  ! 

Just one last question/check: The syntax `myVector& myVector::operator+(const myVector &v, const myVector &wj)` is *wrong* because it returns a reference to a local object, while I should return a new myvec object, right?

Comment: yes, you should be returning a new object, not a reference.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the overloaded operator out of the `myvec` class. Also don't return references to local variables, change the return type to `myvec`.

```
class myvec{
    ...
};

myvec operator+(const myvec& v, const myvec& w);

myvec operator+(const myvec& v, const myvec& w) {
    int d = v.size();
    myvec x(d);
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++) {
        x(i)=v(i)+w(i);
    }
    return x;
}
```

`operator+` takes two arguments, if you declare it inside a class and you give it two regular arguments then you've ended up with an `operator+` that is taking three arguments, which isn't allowed.

For comprehensive advice look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly what you wrote, but it does not compile. It says: `no match for call to ‘(const myvec) (int&)’

Comment: The other issue is that `operator=` is broken in that it leaks memory.  Thus copying will also be broken.

Comment: The line with `x(i) = v(i)+w(i)` @john

Comment: @VoB OK as other have said you have multiple errors in your code. This one can easily be fixed, you need to add a const version of your `operator()`.

Comment: @VoB `class myvec { ...  double operator()(int i) const; ... };`

Comment: inside operator+ `v` and `w` are (correctly) const. But you don't have a const version of your `operator()`. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Now it workds, but why do I have to add a const version? @john

Comment: If you don't have a const version you can't call operator() on a const myvec, which would obviously be a serious limitation. Every method you write should be marked const if it doesn't change the object, or cannot be used to change the object, like your size method for instance. Sometimes this means you need const and non-const versions of the same method.

Answer (score 2):

Complier already gave you the answer: "*must take either zero or one argument*".

Declaration should be `myvec operator+(const myvec&);` and in definition you use `this` like so:

```cpp
myvec myvec::operator +(const myvec& w)
{
    int d = v.size();
    myvec x(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        x(i) = (*this)(i) + w(i);
    }
    return x;
}
```

And don't return reference to local objects.

Comment: Thanks, even if I'm still not familiar with `this`